# Ubuntu fails to Shutdown

Tags: shutdown

When I go to shutdown or use poweroff code in the terminal, it does not complete the shutdown. I use force shutdown by long pressing the power button. How can I overcome this? Help me thanks.

Nixon.

Comment: It often has to do with hardware and drivers, especially graphics. Please edit your question and add hardware specs and, if you try a shutdown command from the answer below, also post where it gets stuck (if it does).

Comment: When you say "shutdown fully", do you mean that it hangs somewhere in the shutdown process and either takes a long time to shutdown, or never shuts down at all, or something else? After you do the shutdown command, you may be able to hit the ESC key to see exactly what's going on, and help determine where it's hanging up.

Answer (score -2):

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do these following commands

To shutdown the system:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

To restart:

```
sudo reboot
```

& one more command for restart:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Another way as one of the user mentioned.

For shutdown:

```
sudo halt
```

or:

```
sudo init 0
```

For restart:

```
sudo init 6
```

You can get more info on the `shutdown` command by using one of the following:

- `shutdown --help`
- `man shutdown`

Please share the results.

Comment: OP is already using those commands and it hangs. This doesn't provide anything useful.